# Find whether a given rational number has a terminating decimal expansion

Tags: rational-numbers, decimal-expansion

> Without actual division find  whether the rational number $\dfrac{1323}{264600}$  is terminating or non terminating.

I know that to solve this, we have to convert the denominator into the formula  $2^n 5^m$.

Comment: If there are only powers of 2 and powers of 5 in the denominator then it will terminate

Answer (score 2):

In order for you to be able to convert the denominator to a number of the form $2^n 5^m$, it needs to a number that is divisible by $2$ or $5$ and no other primes, and that is not the case for $264600$. But, as it turns out, you can make the denominator that way by "simplifying" the fraction: $$\frac{1323}{264600} = \frac{1}{200}.$$ Now observe that $200 = 2^3 5^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$264600 = (100)\cdot(2646) = 2^35^2\cdot1323$$